# Question on "new CNGS/OPERA measurement of neutrino velocity" (hep-ex/1212.1276)

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, neutrinos

A "*new measurement of the limit on muon neutrino velocity with respect to the speed of light* " by the OPERA neutrino experiment in collaboration with CERN has become public recently, as preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.1276

The results concerning neutrinos (i.e., not considering anti-neutrinos) are stated there (in particular in the Conclusions) as

> [...] 
>      
> $\delta t_{[nu]} = (0.6 \pm 0.4 (stat.) \pm 3.0 (syst.))$ ns, 
>  giving the limit 
> $ - 1.8 \times 10^{-6} \lt (v_{nu} - c) / c \lt 2.3 \times 10^{-6} $ at 90 % C.L.

Question (1):
Can the relation between these two results be made more explicit?
How exactly does the result obtained for the quantity $\delta t_{nu}$ "*give*" the stated limit on the quantity $(v_{nu} - c) / c$?

(Note on v2.71828: A second, subsequent question has been removed for separate posting.)

Comment: Velocity is time/distance, right? And they tell you the distance (i.e. baseline) and by how much the arrival times differ from the expectation, right? So...are you stuck on how one should combine statistical and systematic errors, on how to propagate errors through a division operation or what? As for question two you can use the measured distance and time to determine a speed or the measured time and an assumed velocity to measure the distance or the measured distance and an assumed velocity to measure the time.

Comment: @dmckee: "_Velocity is time/distance_"? No: "Speed is distance/duration", where the duration in question is (somewhat misleadingly) often called "time". Now, unfortunately, they haven't given us the TOF value (of the setup being occupied by some particular neutrino, at least on average) explicitly; but at best the value/range of $\delta t$. Nor have they quite given us the applicable distances, e.g. between CNGS "proton beam target" and OPERA "detector element". And the "_baseline_" estimate of Tab. 1 apparently involved not only "CNGS target" and "OPERA reference" but satellites, theodolites

Comment: *'No: "Speed is distance/duration"'* Er...yeah. *::hangs head in embarrasment::* That done, the basesline *is* the estimate of the distance over the measured time. And yeah, they arrived at it after a lot of work ... that's one of the things that makes this a hard measurement. And while I haven't read this paper yet, I'm quite sure they have given you an estimate of the uncertainties involved. Nor do you need to be told the speed from which the $\delta t$ is measured: these are multi GeV neutrinos, so they are expected to go at the speed of light for all reasonable purposes.

Comment: @dmckee: Please read that preprint (and references therein, as necessary)! If my question (as it now stands) can be answered by some unambiguous, straightforward arithmetic (as it well might) then please submit such an answer. I'll admit beforehand that I haven't been able to come up with it (perhaps, embarrasingly, not tried enough) ...
"_these are multi GeV neutrinos, so they are expected to go at the speed of light for all reasonable purposes_". I haven't read that argument being made in the preprint; but this way of thinking was pretty much the idea behind my (now removed) "Question (2)".